# PHP remove duplicated values from mssql fetch array

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I have working php mssql query codes with array but output don't delete same chars. My codes here

```
    $querysfzzrf88 = " SELECT * FROM Style WHERE StyleNo='$StyleNo'";
        $resultsfzzrf88 = mssql_query($querysfzzrf88);


        //display the results 
        while($rowsfzzrf88 = mssql_fetch_array($resultsfzzrf88))
        {
        $Status88 = $rowsfzzrf88["Status"];


   echo $Status88;
}
```

Output

```
 LNNNMMMMMMM
```

Also

```
var_dump($Status88);
```

Gives Like this

```
string(1) "N" string(1) "N" string(1) "N" string(1) "L"
```

I want Output

```
LNM
```

Comment: doing it in php is a waste of cpu time. why not just `select distinct Status from ...`?

Comment: @MarcB how can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE `DISTINCT` in your mysql query to avoid duplicate values:

```
 $querysfzzrf88 = " SELECT DISTINCT status FROM Style WHERE StyleNo='$StyleNo'";
        $resultsfzzrf88 = mssql_query($querysfzzrf88);


        //display the results 
        while($rowsfzzrf88 = mssql_fetch_array($resultsfzzrf88))
        {
        $Status88 = $rowsfzzrf88["Status"];


   echo $Status88;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`count_chars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

```
$str = "LNNNMMMMMMM";

echo count_chars($str, 3);
```

Second parameter is `mode`,

`3 - a string containing all unique characters is returned.`

See demo [here](https://eval.in/482883)

**Edit**

Try this,

```
$str = " LNNNMMMMMMM";
echo preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", $str); or echo preg_replace('/(.)\1+/', '$1', $str);
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/482896)

Comment: you can pass obtained string for `$str.`

Comment: i did   $str = $unique88[0]; echo count_chars($str, 3); but same not work

Comment: Output same  LNNNMMMMMMM like this

Comment: yeah there working good but my output gives with array ( print($unique88[0]); ) and in my codes don't work same output

Comment: checked with new codes ( $str = $unique88[0];
echo preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", $str); ) but same output again

Comment: same bro output same like this i try everything but same

Comment: are u sure you are checking properly??

Comment: with alone string yes true working but in my codes with array don't work

Comment: gives me   NNNLWW   ( but  don't forget output will be different with each query  )

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I misunderstood your question, is this what you've expected:

```
<?php
$chars = 'LNNNMMMMMMM';
$array = str_split($chars);
$array = array_count_values($array);
$array = array_flip($array);
echo implode('', $array);
?>
```

it produces
`LNM`as a result

UPDATE:

```
//display the results
$duplicated88 = $Status88 = $unique88 = array();
while($rowsfzzrf88 = mssql_fetch_array($resultsfzzrf88)){
    $duplicated88[] = $Status88[] = $unique88[] = $rowsfzzrf88["Status"];
}
sort($unique88); 
sort($duplicated88);
$unique88 = implode('', array_unique($unique88));

print($unique88);
```

Comment: i did   $chars = $unique88[0]; and i added your another codes gives me output same  NNNLWW

Comment: gives me  string(1) "N" string(1) "N" string(1) "N" string(1) "L"

Comment: looks like an array...  I can't get the logics of the whole code, though it shouldn't be as it seems at first glance. But if it's an array already you could just try `$array = array_unique($array);` and then `implode()`

Comment: i did $array = array_unique($unique88); echo implode('', $array); now gives output nothing !

Comment: hold on.. you forgot the index `[0]`. shouldn't it be `$array = array_unique($unique88[0]); echo implode('', $array);`

Comment: generally seems quiet weird: `$unique88` is a value of the field `\`Status\``. It should be a string. Why do you treat it as an array in the `foreach... ` loop?

Comment: could you please place `var_dump($unique88);` just right after `$Status88 = $unique88=$rowsfzzrf88["Status"]`

Comment: and what is thet type of `\`Status\``  field in `\`Style\`` table?

Comment: do I understand right that you want to gather all `Status` values from all the rows and then get an array of unique values and a array with all values?

Comment: yeah true dude i want it

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should work. Didn't test, though.. but the logics should be clear.

Comment: made a small change with `implode()` in it. but now $unique88 is a string.

Comment: output gives only  Array

Comment: how could it be? can you `var_dump($unique88);` right after `sort($unique88);` ?

Comment: if you mean `DISTINCT` in sql it won't give you the full array... so I didn't even suggested that ))

Comment: :) yeah sorry for your time